# Trouble adding data to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to add some sample data to an observable collection by declaring a new instance of the Posts class within a private async void and populating the collection. When the app loads, it doesn't show the content. Code compiles with no errors/warnings.

If I was to add the sample data within the Posts() method it's then displayed as expected.

How can I populate my observable collection from within my private async void and have the content displayed when the app is launched?

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource Posts}"
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C#

```
public class Data2 {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public Data2(string title, string author) {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Author = author;
    }
}

public class Posts : ObservableCollection<Data2> {
    public Posts() {
    }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
    public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        GetPosts();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    }

    private async void GetPosts() {
        try {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com/posts.json"));
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var json = ParseData(result);

            Posts posts = new Posts();
            posts.Add(new Data2("Sample Title 1", "Sample Author 1"));
            posts.Add(new Data2("Sample Title 2", "Sample Author 2"));
       }
       catch(HttpRequestException hre) {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(hre);
       }
       catch(Exception ex) {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
       }
    }

    private static RootObject ParseData(string json) {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a view model for the "Posts" property:

```
public class PostsViewModel
{
    public Posts PostData { get; private set; }

    public PostsViewModel()
    {
        PostData = new Posts();
        GetPosts();
    }

    private async void GetPosts() 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now set the page's DataContext to an instance of the view model:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
     private readonly PostsViewModel _viewmodel;

     public MainPage() {
         this.InitializeComponent();

         this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

         _viewmodel = new PostsViewModel();
     }
}
```

And bind the ListView's ItemsSource to the property in the view model:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}"
```

(Of course, you could instead just put the collection in the page's code-behind and set `DataContext=this`, but it is a good idea in general to separate the view-model logic.)

Answer (score 0):

The line above:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource Posts}">
```

should work only if you have previously declared your Static Resouce, as fallows:

```
myWindow.Resources.Add("Posts", Posts);
```

It would be better to use dynamic, though.
You could set your Window data context to your `Posts` class and do the async call to fill the data inside the `Posts` constructor. Then use:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}">
```

You should see the data as soon as you get the response.